# Calculation of hourly and 2 hour moving average for different events in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
Event       DateTime      ModFlow(cfs) ObsFlow(cfs) ModVol(f3)  ObsVol(f3)
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:10  0.7309299   0.6408669   219.27897   192.26007
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:15  0.7177225   0.3482972   215.31675   104.48916
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:20  0.7182343   0.5108359   215.47029   153.25077
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:25  0.7078446   0.6315789   212.35338   189.47367
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:30  0.6973493   0.5201238   209.20479   156.03714
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:35  0.6949614   0.5185758   208.48842   155.57274
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:40  0.6951835   0.6517028   208.55505   195.51084
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:45  0.6869527   0.4659443   206.08581   139.78329
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:50  0.6796721   0.4148607   203.90163   124.45821
Event 01    8/15/2016 3:55  0.6901501   0.4071207   207.04503   122.13621
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:00  0.6912107   0.6996904   207.36321   209.90712
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:05  0.6811846   0.6315789   204.35538   189.47367
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:10  0.6783166   0.5650155   203.49498   169.50465
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:15  0.6752744   0.5572755   202.58232   167.18265
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:20  0.6719815   0.6052632   201.59445   181.57896
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:25  0.66859     0.6563467   200.577     196.90401
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:30  0.6641344   0.4721362   199.24032   141.64086
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:35  0.7217036   0.8436533   216.51108   253.09599
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:40  0.7838766   0.8065016   235.16298   241.95048
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:45  0.9858695   0.6424149   295.76085   192.72447
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:50  1.543869    1.071207    463.1607    321.3621
Event 01    8/15/2016 4:55  3.76313     1.555728    1128.939    466.7184
Event 01    8/15/2016 5:00  6.952304    6.942724    2085.6912   2082.8172
Event 01    8/15/2016 5:05  12.44711    8.373065    3734.133    2511.9195
Event 01    8/15/2016 5:10  18.05204    15.53715    5415.612    4661.145
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:25 0.7944226   1.956656    238.32678   586.9968
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:30 0.7899759   1.743034    236.99277   522.9102
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:35 0.7881337   1.580495    236.44011   474.1485
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:40 0.7872726   1.890093    236.18178   567.0279
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:45 0.7867649   1.883901    236.02947   565.1703
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:50 0.7863836   1.50774     235.91508   452.322
Event 04    4/10/2016 17:55 0.7860502   1.46904     235.81506   440.712
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:00 0.7857358   1.660991    235.72074   498.2973
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:05 0.7942941   1.565015    238.28823   469.5045
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:10 0.8083629   1.982972    242.50887   594.8916
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:15 0.8234028   1.674923    247.02084   502.4769
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:20 0.8384557   1.405573    251.53671   421.6719
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:25 0.8464783   1.503096    253.94349   450.9288
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:30 0.8494487   1.599071    254.83461   479.7213
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:35 0.8503551   1.791022    255.10653   537.3066
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:40 0.8505155   1.605263    255.15465   481.5789
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:45 0.850417    1.726006    255.1251    517.8018
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:50 0.8502218   1.602167    255.06654   480.6501
Event 04    4/10/2016 18:55 0.8500343   1.487616    255.01029   446.2848
Event 04    4/10/2016 19:00 0.8498603   1.928793    254.95809   578.6379
Event 04    4/10/2016 19:05 0.8458332   1.716718    253.74996   515.0154
Event 04    4/10/2016 19:10 0.8399328   1.414861    251.97984   424.4583
Event 04    4/10/2016 19:15 0.8337958   1.674923    250.13874   502.4769
Event 04    4/10/2016 19:20 0.8277948   1.447368    248.33844   434.2104
Event 04    4/10/2016 19:25 0.8244936   1.665635    247.34808   499.6905
```

Values are obtained for every 5 minutes. 
I have many such events in the dataframe.

I would like to have 1 hour and 2 hour moving average for each event in a new dataframe.

How can i possibly do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***pandas 0.19***

```
d1 = df.set_index('DateTime').sort_index()
ma_1h = d1.groupby('Event').rolling('H').mean()
ma_2h = d1.groupby('Event').rolling('2H').mean()

ma_1h.head()
```

[image]

```
ma_2h.head()
```

[image]

---

***pandas < 0.19***
Because the timestamps are at regular intervals, we can grab precise number of rows

```
ma_1h = d1.groupby('Event').rolling(12).mean().dropna()
ma_2h = d1.groupby('Event').rolling(24).mean().dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this error when i ran the code: window must be an integer

Comment: @nish apologies, this is a pandas `0.19` solution

Comment: Ok no problem. I'm using ipython notebook. Is there any way that i can change the above code to make it run? I guess mine runs on pandas 0.19.2 version.

Comment: @nish no.  The work around is messy.  I'll post it if I get time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the pandas [rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) function for that with appropriate window. If you have values at every 5 minutes, to compute the moving average with the 1 hours window, the parameter window you will pass will be 12, and 24 in the case of 2 hours. For example check this
[Moving Average- Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060842/moving-average-pandas)

Comment: Can u please explain why is it 12 and 6 for windows values?? how is it taken??

Comment: It is a simple math, for your data 12 rows make an hour as your frequency of data is 5 minutes.