# Pandas: Rolling mean over array of windows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42152692/2327328), I can calculate multiple rolling means

```
d1 = df.set_index('DateTime').sort_index()
ma_1h = d1.groupby('Event').rolling('H').mean()
ma_2h = d1.groupby('Event').rolling('2H').mean()
```

But how can I do this performantly if I want to do it for a list of arrays?

```
window_array = ['H','3H','6H','9H'] # etc
```

And that my rolling means are included back into my original dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need convert offsets and create new `DataFrame`s in loop by list comprehension, last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

df1 = pd.concat([d1.groupby('Event').rolling(to_offset(x)).mean() for x in window_array], 
                axis=1, 
                keys=window_array)
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='38T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': rng, 'a': range(10), 'Event':[4] * 3 + [3] * 3 + [1] * 4})  
print (df)


from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
window_array = ['H','3H','6H','9H']


d1 = df.set_index('DateTime').sort_index()
a = pd.concat([d1.groupby('Event')['a'].rolling(to_offset(x)).mean() for x in window_array], 
              axis=1, 
              keys=window_array)
print (a)
                             H   3H   6H   9H
Event DateTime                               
1     2017-04-03 03:48:00  6.0  6.0  6.0  6.0
      2017-04-03 04:26:00  6.5  6.5  6.5  6.5
      2017-04-03 05:04:00  7.5  7.0  7.0  7.0
      2017-04-03 05:42:00  8.5  7.5  7.5  7.5
3     2017-04-03 01:54:00  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
      2017-04-03 02:32:00  3.5  3.5  3.5  3.5
      2017-04-03 03:10:00  4.5  4.0  4.0  4.0
4     2017-04-03 00:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
      2017-04-03 00:38:00  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5
      2017-04-03 01:16:00  1.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window_array = ['H','3H','6H','9H'] # etc
for window in window_array:
    d1[window] = d1.groupby('Event').rolling(window).mean()
```