# How to perform rolling average on a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that I'm trying to get a fairly complicated statistic for and I can't seem to figure it out. I have an initial dataframe for a years worth of data at hourly sampling, for a dozen nodes, that looks like this (datetimes are dtype=datetime):

```
df =
          Price_Node_Name   Price_Type      Local_Datetime_HourEnding  Price 
1592204    FRANKLIN_FALL_HYD   GENERATOR     2016-08-18 01:00:00       16.91 
1592205    FRANKLIN_FALL_HYD   GENERATOR     2016-08-18 02:00:00       16.32 
1592206    FRANKLIN_FALL_HYD   GENERATOR     2016-08-18 03:00:00       15.11 
1592207    FRANKLIN_FALL_HYD   GENERATOR     2016-08-18 04:00:00       13.53  
1592208    FRANKLIN_FALL_HYD   GENERATOR     2016-08-18 05:00:00       13.22
```

I then created a multi index dataframe with node name and datetime, followed by a grouping by node name:

```
df = df.set_index(['Price_Node_Name', 'Local_Datetime_HourEnding'])
df = df.groupby(level=0)
df =
                                                   Price_Type    Price
Price_Node_Name     Local_Datetime_HourEnding                  
FRANKLIN_FALL_HYD   2016-08-18 01:00:00             GENERATOR     16.91
                    2016-08-18 02:00:00             GENERATOR     17.05
                    2016-08-18 03:00:00             GENERATOR     18.09
                    2016-08-18 04:00:00             GENERATOR     12.75
```

What I am trying to do is, for each node, do a rolling 4-hour average of the prices and then average those rolling averages by month, so in the end I'll have an output that looks like this for each node:

```
1          2            3           4           5           6           7   ...
1 42.219417 30.506111   43.796000   33.946379   26.519583   24.253793   25.108167
2 43.239417 29.524074   40.186250   33.953017   30.221167   21.995431   23.777917
3 43.019167 30.988611   37.308879   34.901207   31.284333   20.896897   22.124083
4 40.920323 30.757679   35.237984   35.696500   31.725887   19.924583   20.755323
5 41.639839 30.606875   34.285000   36.307333   31.071935   18.862333   20.663790
6 38.041048 28.899911   32.746290   34.443333   24.454032   17.848750   19.732097
7 36.654516 24.987321   29.178065   31.912167   21.423145   16.796083   19.360081
8 37.500000 25.608750   29.166774   31.022083   20.673306   17.120167   19.837016
...
```

With months running across the top and hours running down the side, each value being that months hourly average price.

I'm having trouble looping through the dataframe and building a master data frame of the rolling-average monthly averages of each node. Help! I think I'm in over my head on this one.

My loop currently looks like this, which I'm not even sure what each step is accomplishing.

```
df_month_master = []
for node in df:
    for i in range(1, 13):
        df_month = df.loc[df['Local_Datetime_HourEnding'].dt.month == i]
        df_month['Price'] = df_month['Price'].rolling(4).mean()
        df_month = df.groupby([df_month['Local_Datetime_HourEnding'].dt.month,
                                                     df_month['Local_Datetime_HourEnding'].dt.hour]).mean()
        df_month_master.append(df_month)
df_month_master_df = pd.DataFrame(df_month_master)
print(df_month_master_df)
```

It works when I don't multi index or groupby nodes, and manually go node by node, but naturally I want to be able to loop through and have a nice output. AND I would like to understand the manipulations that are happening.

Comment: Is [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving Average- Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060842/moving-average-pandas)

Comment: It's part of it. I also want to then average those rolling averages for each hour in the month. I want to average all the 1am's for each day in January, etc. Edit: And understand each part of the dataframe manipulation.

Comment: I think you could do that with the above functions just by how you slice your dataframe and how you specify your window.

Comment: Right, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to go about that. I don't have a lot of intuition on what happens in indexing and creating groupby dataframes.

Comment: If `df` is your DataFrame, could you run `df.head(10).to_dict(orient='list')` and paste that as part of your question?  It would make it a lot easier to check a potential answer.