# How to create three separate columns conditionally from three other existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas

| Year | A1 | A2 | A3 | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1992 | Sal | Ray | Tom | 5 |
| 2003 | Tom | Peter | Vick | 3 |
| 2001 | Ray | Jill | Kim | 4 |
| 1998 | Vick | Sal | Ray | 2 |
| 1996 | Peter | Kim | Sal | 3 |
| 2002 | Tom | Kim | Peter | 2 |

- How can a I create 3 new columns that takes each person regardless of which column they are in in order by year and outputs a running Tier average without using the current Tier. If its the first time appearing then all 1's.  All new columns for year 1992 will be 1's.
- answer should be
- column A1r =[1,1,1,3.5,5,3]
- column A2r =[1,1,4,1,3.5,2.5]
- column A3r =[1,5,5,3,3,2]

Comment: Kindly post your expected dataframe

Comment: you can calculate moving average in pandas using [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060842/moving-average-pandas)