# Mean for column based on time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes. The first one has timepoints and values for different measurements.
df1:

| time | valueX | valueY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 11:27:25 | 10 | 3 |
| 2021-06-05 11:27:25 | 15 | 5 |

and a second dataframe with a lot of temperature measurements.
df2:

| time | temp |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-05 11:25:25 | 20.1 |
| 2021-05-05 11:35:25 | 20.2 |
| 2021-05-05 11:45:25 | 20.1 |
| 2021-05-05 11:55:25 | 21.2 |
| 2021-05-05 12:05:25 | 20.1 |

I would like to have another column in df1 that gives me the mean temperature of the last 3 days for the timepoint in column 1 of df1. And I have no glue how to do that...
I tried something like this

```
df1['mean_tepm'] = df2[(df1['time']-df2['time'] < timedelta(days=3) & (df2[(df1['time']-df2['time'] < timedelta(days=0)]['temperature'].mean()
```

But it gave me the same value for every row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving Average Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060842/moving-average-pandas)

Comment: Not really. The problem is that I have different numbers of measurements per day. So on one day the temperature was measured every ten minutes and the next day every 15.