# 6 last month (moving) Average Column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, average, moving-average

I have the following df: [date is the index]

```
print(df)

               country        values           
date                        
2022-06-01     ES             2                  
2022-07-01     ES             2        
2022-08-01     ES             3         
2022-09-01     ES             3  
2022-10-01     ES             5  
2022-11-01     ES             5  
2022-12-01     ES             6  
2023-01-01     ES             6  
2023-02-01     ES             NaN 
2022-06-01     IT             1                    
2022-07-01     IT             1  
2022-08-01     IT             2  
2022-09-01     IT             2  
2022-10-01     IT             3  
2022-11-01     IT             3  
2022-12-01     IT             4 
2023-01-01     IT             4
2023-02-01     IT             NaN
```

I need to generate a new column called 'moving_average' that is the average of the last 6 month by country (considering current month). The values that don't have 6 months information should be NaN. **And this new value should replace the NaN of the corresponding month.** This should be the output:

```
               country        values      moving_average 
date                        
2022-06-01     ES             2           NaN         
2022-07-01     ES             2           NaN
2022-08-01     ES             3           NaN
2022-09-01     ES             3           NaN
2022-10-01     ES             5           NaN
2022-11-01     ES             5           ---> AVG(2,2,3,3,5,5) = 3.33
2022-12-01     ES             6           ---> AVG(2,3,3,5,5,6) = 4 
2023-01-01     ES             6           ---> AVG(3,3,5,5,6,6) = 4.67 --> Should replace 2023-02-01 value (that is NaN) with this AVG
2023-02-01     ES             4.67        ---> AVG(3,5,5,6,6,4.67) = 4.945
2022-06-01     IT             1           NaN         
2022-07-01     IT             1           NaN
2022-08-01     IT             2           NaN
2022-09-01     IT             2           NaN
2022-10-01     IT             3           NaN
2022-11-01     IT             3           ---> AVG(1,1,2,2,3,3) = 2
2022-12-01     IT             4           ---> AVG(1,2,2,3,3,4) = 2.5
2023-01-01     IT             4           ---> AVG(2,2,3,3,4,4) = 3 --> Should replace 2023-02-01 value (that is NaN) with this AVG
2023-02-01     IT             3           ---> AVG(2,3,3,4,4,3) = 3.167
```

How we can achieve this?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving Average Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060842/moving-average-pandas)

Comment: Why month 10 has not been included?